# How to pause a movie using Video Player (Galaxy S)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, video

Galaxy-S (Vibrant), Android 2.1

I was watching Avatar the other day and paused it.  When I played it again later, it restarted at the beginning.  Is it possible to resume play from where I left off, or bookmark a position or something?  Or is there a different/better player that does this?  Thanks!

Comment: I'd change the main question to tell its for the Galaxy S. The default player should remember where you was as long as you don't close it. I don't have any experience with other players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My T-Mobile Vibrant (Samsung Galaxy S) just received a OTA update from T959UVJFD to T959UVJI6. It appears that this may have fixed the problem you are describing.  It no longer is a problem for me after this update was installed.  It is also mentioned at the [xda-developers site](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=8539388&highlight=video#post8539388) along with other changes that were included in the update.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the default movies and player that came with my Galaxy S (AT*T Captivate) without this error. It may be possible that there was a timeout (how long did you pause for?).
You may also want to try the [doubletwist](http://www.doubletwist.com/) video player to see if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my Samsung Vibrant.  I just started dropping bookmarks before "pausing" and resuming from them.

Comment: How do you drop a bookmark?